# How to use WmdSimilarity function provided in gensim along with word embeddings which are in numpy.ndarray data type

Tags: python-3.6, gensim, word2vec, numpy-ndarray, wmd

Using Word2vec (skip-gram) model in tensorflow , I wrote the code to obtain word embeddings from document-set.
The final embeddings are in numpy.ndarray format

Now to obtain similar documents , I need to use the WMD(Word Movers Distance) algorithm.

(I don't have much knowledge of gensim)
The gensim.similarities.WmdSimilarity() requires the embeddings to be in KeyedVectors data type (seems like) -- 
What can I do to implement WMD in my code.I have a tight deadline and can't give much time to writing the code of WMD from scratch .

Comment: Is there any other text similarity method which takes word embeddings as input?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for similarity between 2 words, use

```
my_gensim_word2vec_model.most_similar('king')
```

`my_gensim_word2vec_model` is the gensim model, of course, not your own tensorflow model.

If you want the most similar to a bunch of words:

`my_gensim_word2vec_model.most_similar(positive=['king', 'queen', 'rabbit'])`

Check the [gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)

If your're looking for similarity between sentences or documents, you're better off using doc2vec which gives a vector for all the vocabulary words and documents.

Or take the average of all words in the sentence/document to get the vector for that document. Then get the cosine similarity between the averages of the two sentences to be compared.

For example:

```
Similarity("Hello World", "Hi there") = CosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2)
"Hello World" -> (Vec("Hello") + Vec("World"))/2 -> vec1
"Hi there" -> (Vec("Hi") + Vec("there"))/2 -> vec2
```

(Your question is unclear. What is document set? What is your task?)
Hope this helps.